# exporting datagrid to pdf in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, datagrid

Im writing a simple app that allows a user to export the created datagrid (here its dataGridView1) to a pdf file with a little help from itextsharp reference.
I've found a useful sample code on the internet but im having some problems in configuring it to export the data that the user enters during his work with the app. The user enters the data in textbox, saves it to the datagrid.
The result pdf file only contains the headers taken from the textbox and no cell content (data entered and saved by users using the textboxes).

Here is the code

```
        //Creating iTextSharp Table from the DataTable data
        PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.ColumnCount);
        pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;
        pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 30;
        pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;

        //Adding Header row
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText));
            cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240);
            pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
        }            

        //Exporting to PDF
        string folderPath = "C:\\Users\\Marcus\\PDFs\\";
        if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
        }
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(folderPath + "DataGridViewExport.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add another loop inside the `foreach` loop that actually iterates through each row.  And add's the cell value to the pdfTable.  It should be quite obvious that `new PdfPcell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText));` will only grab the headers

Comment: could you provide me with a sample loop?

Comment: `foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.rows)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.cells)
    {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.Value));
    }
}`

Comment: just actually add that loop after the current foreach loop.  Don't nest it.

Comment: Are you sure? It says that "A local variable named 'cell' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'cell', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else" and 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You have to think for yourself a bit here.  just rename the `cell` variable to whatever you want to call it... find the equivalent property of `Value` which is probably like `Text` or even use `ToString`  Basically the idea it what I showed you.  Iterate through all the rows and all the cells in each row.  Then add that cells value to the PDF Table..

Comment: `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) 
            { foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) 
                { PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.ToString())); } }`  still exports an empty table though. I guess ill just try a different approach.  @chancea

Comment: You have to then add `cell2` to the `pdfTable` like how you did for the header cells ==> `pdfTable.AddCell(cell2);`

Comment: Sorry ignore that first part (now deleted) of my last comment I read the code wrong. `PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.ToString()));` is correct

Comment: Done. `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) 
            { foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) 
                { PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.ToString())); 
                pdfTable.AddCell(cell2);
            }` it doesnt import the right stuff though, the row is now filled with `DataGridVie
wTextBoxC
ell {
ColumnInde
x=0,
RowIndex=
0 }` not the actual data. @chancea Sorry for trolling

Comment: I think it's just getting confusing typing code into the comments.  Too unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is your header code (which you said works so lets leave that alone)

```
//Adding Header row
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText));
    cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240);
    pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
}   


//Lets add code that actually gets the cell contents down below it:

//add the cell contents
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) { 
    foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) { 
        //we need to call .Value to get the value of the cell, but since a Phrase takes in
        //a String, we need to convert the .Value to a String using .ToString()
        PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.Value.ToString()));  //this .Value property is that of a DataGridViewCell
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell);
    } 
}
```

[DataGridViewCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should have a [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property.  Use that to get your value of the cells.

Comment: `foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText));
            cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240);
            pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
            
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) 
            { foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row.Cells.ToString()));
                pdfTable.AddCell(cell2);
            } }` this the code @chancea, export still fail

Comment: Yeah you need to change `row.Cells.ToString()` to `cell.Value`

Comment: `Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'iTextSharp.text.Phrase.Phrase(string)' has some invalid arguments` and `Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'` i think im gonna give up on this thank you for your patience though @chancea

Comment: Should it throw a null reference exception? @chancea

Comment: I have added a null check `if (cell.Value !=null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cell.Value.ToString());
        }` and it says the value of the cell is 1. Im kinda lost.